# Wso2 APIManager 3.2.0 How can download Analytics for it?

Tags: wso2, analytics, wso2-api-manager

Wso2 APIManager 3.2.0 How can download Analytics for it?
I can't find link for download.

1- I want a link for download.

2- Analytics for this API Manager version Is Stram Processor or not?

3-Analytic for this version is free or not?

4- I want a link for download wso2 API Manager 3.2.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can get the analytics pack in https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/releases/tag/v3.2.0
2. In the 3.2 version you can't configure stream processor for analytics.
3. Yes. follow the doc to configure it.  https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/analytics/configuring-apim-analytics/#configuring-apim-analytics
4. Get the API-M pack in same link I have mentioned in 1. https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/releases/tag/v3.2.0

Comment: your answer is very good. please answer question 4 ? thank you

Comment: You can get the API-M Pack from the same link I have mentioned in 1. https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/releases/tag/v3.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Previous product distributions are available in https://wso2.com/api-management/previous-releases/